# Installing oh-my-zsh without git

Tags: software-installation, zsh, oh-my-zsh

How can I install oh-my-zsh from master on the machine behind firewall and without git and internet access?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a fork of the git repository for oh-my-zsh. https://github.com/atr2600/ohmyzsh

I added an offline install script. What you have to do is unzip the contents of the git repository into the airgapped machine.

1. SCP or RSYNC the files into your system
2. `mkdir ~/.oh-my-zsh`
3. `unzip -j ./ohmyzsh-master.zip -d ~/.oh-my-zsh/`
4. `cd ~./oh-my-zsh`
5. `./offline-installer.sh`
6. ENJOY!!

Answer (score -1):

Go to a machine that has internet access and/or git, [download the complete repository](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/archive/master.zip) or copy the .oh-my-zsh/ directory, then after doing a backup, replace the `~/.zshrc` file with the one from the templates:

```
cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc
```

And (re)start your zsh.

Comment: And what about plugins?

Comment: @user72394 what about them?

Comment: Don't works without git:( # zsh
compdef: unknown command or service: git
compdef: unknown command or service: git
compdef: unknown command or service: git
compdef: unknown command or service: git
compdef: unknown command or service: git
compdef: unknown command or service: git
~  ~  <--this is prompt